# How to use jquery to delete element after it is moved

Tags: jquery

I want to dynamically create, delete div, which will be moved around after created.

1) This seems work after create/delete. If simply doing create/delete repeatedly, 'hello-id' div does not appear in . (May be not... the deleted item will show up again. See step #2)

```
// HTLM
<body>
   <div id='insert1'>
      <div id='insert2'>
      </div>
   </div>
</body>

// Javascript
$("body").append($("<div id='hello-id'>hello</div>"));
$('#hello-id').remove()


// HTML after create/delete. Correct! 'hello-id' div is removed 
// from <body>. It can't be found. 
<body>
   <div id='insert1'>
      <div id='insert2'>
      </div>
   </div>
</body>
```

2) This does not work if 'hello-id' div is moved. It can't be deleted once moved. Also, the deleted items in step #1 will show up again and the number of appearance depends on create/delete cycles.

```
// HTLM
<body>
   <div id='insert1'>
      <div id='insert2'>
      </div>
   </div>
</body>

// Javascript
$("body").append($("<div id='hello-id'></div>"));
$('#hello-id').insertBefore($('#insert2'));
//$('hello-id').remove()

// HTML after. Assume #1 is performed with 1 cycle.  'hello-id' div 
// is removed from <body>. 
// 2 'hello-id' div show up. BUT, it should be 1!
<body>
   <div id='insert1'>
      <div id='hello-id'>
      </div>
      <div id='hello-id'>
      </div>
      <div id='insert2'>
      </div>
   </div>
</body>
```

3) Perform remove. But, there is 1 left.

```
// Javascript
$('#hello-id').remove()

// HTML
<body>
   <div id='insert1'>
      <div id='hello-id'>
      </div>
      <div id='insert2'>
      </div>
   </div>
</body>
```

I am sure create/delete is performed in pair at step #1. By the way, during the process Jquery $('hello-id').show(),  $('hello-id').hide() are performed.

What's wrong with Jquery remove() function if element is moved around?

Comment: `$('hello-id')` is like saying: "jQuery go find this element: `<hello-id></hello-id>`", clearly not your case. You need a `#` :)

Comment: I corrected $('hello-id') to $('#hello-id') in my question. Sorry about that. I abstracted the issue from a big code base. I feel very strange why #1 did remove the 'hello-id' div, only if I do insert (it moved the div in <body> to other location, I noticed 2 items are inserted. 1 item may be the deleted item which is performed in #1 create/delete cycle. I am using jquery-1.12.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I think I got the problem now.

Each time you execute that:

```js
$("<div id='hello-id'></div>");
```

jQuery will create a new element, so that way you will get duplicated div with id="hello-id".

You need to keep that element in a variable and append the variable, something like this:

```js
var divHello = $("<div id='hello-id'></div>");

// Step 1
$("body").append(divHello);
$('#hello-id').remove();

// Step 2
$("body").append(divHello);
$('#hello-id').insertBefore($('#insert2'));

// Step 2 again (should not duplicate now)
$("body").append(divHello);
$('#hello-id').insertBefore($('#insert2'));

// Step 3 (now you'll be able to remove, just because there is only one div hello-id)
$('#hello-id').remove();
```

That way (appending divHello variable instead "$()" jQuery selector), you will not create a new div "hello-id", it will just "put" and "move" the existing div "hello-id" in html.

Let me know if this solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had tried you code and it worked normally. by the way, your examples is missing # in $('#hello-id') and $('#insert2'), see if your problem is it...

```js
$("body").append($("<div id='hello-id'>Hello</div>"));
$('#hello-id').insertBefore($('#insert2'));
$('#hello-id').remove();
```

```html
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
   <div id='insert1'>
      <div id='insert2'>
      </div>
   </div>
</body>
```

...If the problem is not because the "#", so I had noticed that in your case, is duplicated tag:

```html
<div id='hello-id'></div>
```

But in Code Snippet above it doesn't duplicate and works, maybe it is a version issue.

But the point is, you "can not" have 2 or more elements with the same "id" in your DOM, so if your have 2 elements with the same id, jquery will remove only one.

**You can fix that of 2 ways:**

1 - Try another jQuery version just to see if **div id='hello-id'** stop to duplicate, if yes, your code probably will work.

2 - You can set a class instead id:

```html
<div class='hello-class'></div>
```

That way when you remove "$('.hello-class').remove();", jquery remove all elements with this same class.

Comment: Thank you. I corrected 'hello-id' to '#hello-id'. I am pretty sure it's not the cause. Can you do #1, and then #2. Your code does not match original sequence. My Jquery is v1.12.4. May be too old.

Comment: My original code is: click a button1, 'hello-id' div is created hidden in <body>; click button 1 again; delete 'hello-id'; click button 1 again; click an element 'insert2', move 'hello-id' div before 'insert2' div and show 'hello-id' div. I find 2 'hello-id' div in front of 'insert2'. Click button 1 again, you can delete 1 'hello-id'. 2 'hello-id' showed up is not correct behavior.

Comment: Tried v3.4.1. Same result.

Comment: Can you post your code just how is it, the original sequence with the button, etc, or post without button, but a code that you got the same problem? That way I'll be able to reproduce the problem and test it.

Comment: I mean, you have 3 code example above following steps, I tried to reproduce the problem, but as you said my code was different, so can you provide a unique html and js to reproduce the problem in a sandbox like jsfiddle, etc?

Comment: I figured out my root problem was my class 'destructor' did not delete click event handler, which results in 'hello-id' is used multiple times. The class of handling  'hello-id' div was not deleted completely. Thank you all for your help.